# Semi-automatically fix orphan words

Tags: auxiliary-files, line-numbering

I'm trying to build a script to semi-automatically fix orphan words.
To do that I need a way to write an auxiliary file that contains some data. The idea is to have a command like:

```
Wor\OrphansSpotter[keyword]{d W}ord.\n\n
```

The function of such a command should be to write a line:

```
keyword X Y
```

in an auxiliary file, where X is the line number (of the page?) of the first char in the command argument and Y is the line number of the last char in the command argument.

In my temporary modified .tex file I shoud have some occurrences of such a command and my final auxiliary file content should be something like:

```
keyword1 15 15
keyword2 20 21
keyword3 3 3
keyword4 11 12
```

Scanning this file, if `X!=Y`, I could run a query-replacement command, e.g.

```
"Word Word." --> "Word~Word."
```

in my text editor (emacs).

Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it (I mean the LaTeX stuff).

Comment: It could be that you want to modify really  `\parfillskip` and `\emergencystretch`?  This not analyze in any way which word is, but can avoid  last lines with less of X % of the test width, or even avoid  incomplete lines of any length, like  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185536/11604).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "orphan word". Is it the last word in a paragraph on a line by itself?

In 2007 I wrote a column in TUGboat describing how to adjust paragraph shapes among which was one whereby the last line was "not too short" which may answer your problem. See https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb28-2/tb89glister.pdf

Comment: Yes, Your "orphan word" definition matches what I mean. Unfortunately I need to fix orphans in the way I described above. I'm not allowed to redefine LaTeX settings (or define new ones).

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi How strange you are not allowed to alter your LaTeX code. Why not just hand edit your document? It seems to me that you will want to use `\OrphanSpotter` on the last word in every paragraph. Why not just read the printed output to spot any orphans and adjust your text appropriately?

Comment: It'a complicated... I'm not an author but an editor and my boss does not allow me to do certain things on the LaTeX code. I indeed want to use `\OrphanSpotter` on the last word in every paragraph. But not manually. I'm very goog with emacs-lisp and regular expressions. I'm always looking for ways to do my job faster.

Comment: Obviously, in the and I will read the printed output and adjust text appropriately, but i'm trying to reduce manual interventions.